# 2 apps on the same server, different ports. First app can't see the second

Tags: python, node.js, apache, ubuntu, flask

I have 2 apps on the same VPS (ubuntu), same domain. First is Node.js app, running on port :80
The second is Python (Flask) app running under apache on port :3000
The python app has simple API with one endpoint /test.

I'm trying to connect to the endpoint using Postman, directly in a browser or from different server and it works. But when trying connect from the Node app from the same server I'm getting 404. CORS is disabled.

What can be wrong?

**For example:**
my Flask app's endpoint is running on http://myvps.com:3000/test
When trying fetch the data on computer or different server
`fetch('http://myvps.com:3000/test').then(...)` it works. Also, when I'm visiting myvps.com:3000/test in a browser it works as well.

But when doing exactly the same thing `fetch('http://myvps.com:3000/test').then(...)` on my Node app (on the save server but port :80- http://myvps.com) the fetch return 404 - Not Found. Any different, external API works.

Vhost configuration:

```
<VirtualHost [server_ip]:3000>
    ServerName ....
    ErrorLog /home/www/python/logs/error.log
    CustomLog /home/www/python/logs/access.log combined

    WSGIDaemonProcess pythonapp user=www-data group=www-data threads=5 python-path=/home/www/python/pythonapp:/home/www/python/pythonapp/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages
    WSGIProcessGroup pythonapp
    WSGIScriptAlias / /home/www/python/pythonapp/pythonapp.wsgi application-group=pythonapp process-group=pythonapp

    <Directory /home/www/python/>
        Order Allow,Deny
        Allow from all
        Require all granted
    </Directory>

    Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
    Header set Access-Control-Allow-Methods "POST, GET, OPTIONS, DELETE, PUT"
    Header set Access-Control-Max-Age "1000"
    Header set Access-Control-Allow-Headers "x-requested-with, Content-Type, origin, authorization, accept, client-security-token"
</VirtualHost>
```

Node.js app is running on express.

Comment: Please provide a minimal example

Comment: Sure, just added example to the question

Comment: Have you tested it on localhost?

Comment: We're a little bit blind here. Can you add the vhost configuration?

Comment: Have not tested on localhost. 
Just added vhost to the question

Comment: @RiccardoBucco it is working on localhost. So it is something with server/apache configuration?

Comment: @brc what about the nodejs app vhost config? this one seems to be working fine.

Comment: Node doesn't have vhost config. It's running on express, default port.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was fighting with that all day and I found the reason 1 hour after posting here...
The problem was vhost configuration. I've chnaged `<VirtualHost [server_ip]:3000>` to `<VirtualHost *:3000>` and it stared working.
Thanks for the replies!